# Resize JTextArea only vertical

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, jtextarea

What is the best way to resize JTextArea vertical? I think I shoud put JTextArea into JScrollPane (and I can make a simple pane with scrollbar). But I want to JTextArea scroll by mouse vertical. I tried to use class according to this tut.:
https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/, but it is able to resize component with all sides.

I want something like here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_resize&preval=vertical

or something like textarea which you use to post answer to topic here.

**EDIT:**

My piece of code with class ComponentResizer (from https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/)

```
package textsamplerdemo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TextSamplerDemo extends JPanel {

    public TextSamplerDemo() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        ComponentResizer componentResizer = new ComponentResizer();
        componentResizer.registerComponent(scrollPane);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextSamplerDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new TextSamplerDemo());
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an appropriate layout & layout constraint. `LINE_START` or `LINE_END` of a `BorderLayout` would do it. Be sure to give the text area a defined number of columns and rows to suggest a size to the layout.

Comment: You mean something like this? `setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10,20);
        
        ComponentResizer componentResizer = new ComponentResizer();
        componentResizer.registerComponent(textArea);
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson specified `LINE_START` or `LINE_END`; try it to see why; as code in comments is hard to read, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach; use `@` to address participants by name.

Comment: @trashgod I have edited my question with example. Sorry, and I do not know how to implement `LINE_START` and` LINE_END` to work it properly.

Comment: @Jan444444, `I do not know how to implement LINE_START and` LINE_END` to work it properly.` use "LINE_START" instead of "PAGE_START". And there is no need for the ComponentResizer. The scrollpane will fill vertical space available in the frame. I suggest you also read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) ro learn the basics of how to use a `BorderLayout` and other layout managers.

Comment: @camickr, I think I understand that JScrollPane will fill available vertical space. But I do not want to do it. I want to "set" height of JScrollPane and I want to set also feature to "drag by mouse" bottom of this pane and resize it vertical. For example like JSplitPane has but wirhout second component. I want to achive the same as here: [vertical resize](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_resize&preval=vertical)

Comment: Yes, well you miss the point of how to use layout managers. Being able to resize a split pane makes sense because the total space available to the split pane doesn't change. What does change is the spaces allocated to each component. If you want to manually resize a scrollpane then you need to use a null layout otherwise the layout manager will just reset the size of the component. You should not be using a null layout for something like this. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: @camickr, so in other words it is not so easy to manage it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> but it is able to resize component with all sides.

The `ComponentResizer` supports a `maximum size` property. So you can do something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
ScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
Dimension d = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
d.height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
cr.setMaximumSize(d));
cr.registerComponent(scrollPane);
```